# Free Database for my workstation to manage 20 GB csv files

Tags: database

I am using free version of SQL Server 2016 Developer edition but it doesn’t allow more than 10,240 MB of space in one database. Please suggest any nice free version database which I can use to manage 20 GB files that gets generated very month and then analyse and compare both of them.

Comment: The **Developer** edition of SQL Server has **no such limit** at 10 GB - that's the **Express** edition you're thinking about. The Developer edition is a full-blown Enterprise edition - just without a license to use in a commercial, productive environment

Comment: @marc_s my bad, let me check the version again. But regardless, it doesn’t allow the DB size to be configured more that 10 Gigs.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/